# .tar files on OS X Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, tar, powerpc

I am about to throw my shiny new MBP out the window. How am I supposed to deal with .tar files with OS X Lion? Every single application I try to download spits out some dumb error about PowerPC architecture not being supported.

Any help is *greatly* appreciated.

Note: More specifically, my latest issue is trying to install Ruby Version Manager so I can update to 1.9.3.

EDIT:

Any tar command gives me this error:

Launch of "tar" failed: the PowerPC architecture is no longer supported.

I am going to move this question over to the appropriate StackExchange site. Sorry for the mispost; I'm having trouble keeping the different sites straight in my head!

Comment: Not a programming question.  You simply need to find a deflator that works with the older PowerPC models.  I am pretty sure that the built in archiver supports tar...

Comment: Try asking this question at http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Wait, if your mac book pro is new, it should have an intel chip, why is it complaining about PPC?

Comment: Hmmm...they'll install the OS, but not a compatible tar?!?

Comment: So it didn't get migrated because there were not enough votes for Super User (and there is no user accessible migration to Apple.SE). You could flag it for a moderator---they might be willing. Or you could just go and re-post on Apple.SE. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
tar xvf file.tar
tar zxvf file.tar.gz
tar jxvf file.tar.bz2
```

The `z` says the tarball was compressed with `gzip`. The `j` says the tarball was compressed with `bzip2`.

`x` extracts the data. `v` gives verbose output. `f` gives the filename of the tarball (since you're probably not using a tape drive).

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing tar with a third party package management tool like [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [macports](http://www.macports.org/). I'm a fink guy, myself. There is also homebrew about which I know very little.

In fink you want the `tar` package. Shocking, eh?

### Obsoleted by the edit

What's wrong with `/usr/bin/tar`? Or is that not to be found on Lion even after you've installed the developer tools?

From the command line try

```
$ tar xfv <tar_file>
```

or if it has a `.tgz` ending

```
$ tar xzfv <tar_file>
```